# Pandas Boolean Row Selection with Mixed Types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select rows in a data frame `data` based on two conditions. One is on a column called let's call it `id` is meant to be selected on membership in a list `keep` and another, call it `toggle`, is meant to be checked on an equality condition.

My code is:

```
 new_data = data[(data['id'].isin(keep) & data['toggle']==2)]
```

which returns a data frame with zero rows. However if I do

```
new_data = data[data['id'].isin(keep)]
new_data = new_data[new_data['toggle']==2]
```

I get a data frame with several rows which is what SHOULD happen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `new_data = data.loc[(data['id'].isin(keep)) & (data['toggle']==2)]`

Comment: Use `data[data['id'].isin(keep) & data['toggle'].eq(2)]`, or parentheses, see [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)